# AngularJS Inserting and displaying from database

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I am using AngularJS to insert and then display data from my MYSQL database. Displaying the data was successfully working but then when I added the inserting feature the display feature broke. Now inside the table which is supposed to be displaying the data I am just getting the variable e.g {{x.ID}} or {{x.Make}}.
Any help is appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<title> Display data from Mysql Database Using AngularJS with PHP</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>  
<body>  
<div class="container">
    <h1 align="center">Insert Data Into Database using Angular JS with PHP Mysql</h1>
    <div ng-app="sa_insert" ng-controller="controller">
        <label>ID</label><input type="text" name="ID" ng-model="name" class="form-control"><br/>
        <label>Make</label><input type="text" name="Make" ng-model="Make" class="form-control"><br/>
        <label>Model</label><input type="text" name="Model" ng-model="Model" class="form-control"><br/>
        <label>Reg</label><input type="text" name="Reg" ng-model="Reg" class="form-control"><br/>
        <label>Owner</label><input type="text" name="Owner" ng-model="Owner" class="form-control"><br/>
        <label>Image</label><input type="text" name="Image" ng-model="Image" class="form-control"><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="insert" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="insert()" value="Insert">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Script -->
<script>
var app = angular.module("sa_insert", []);
app.controller("controller", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.insert = function() {
        $http.post(
            "statementinsert.php", {
                'ID': $scope.ID,
                'Make': $scope.Make,
                'Model': $scope.Model,
                'Reg': $scope.Reg,
                'Owner': $scope.Owner,
                'Image': $scope.Image,

            }
        ).success(function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $scope.ID = null;
            $scope.Make = null;
            $scope.Model = null;
            $scope.Reg = null;
            $scope.Owner = null;
            $scope.Image = null;
        });
    }
});
</script>
<div class="container">
    <h3 align="center">Display data from Mysql Database Using AngularJS with PHP</h3>
    <div ng-app="sa_display" ng-controller="controller" ng-init="display_data()">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Make</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Reg</th>
                <th>Owner</th>
                <th>Image</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
                <td>{{x.ID}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Make}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Model}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Age}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Reg}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Owner}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Image}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Script -->  
<script>
    var app = angular.module("sa_display", []);
    app.controller("controller", function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.display_data = function() {
            $http.get("statement.php")
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.names = data;
                });
        }
    });
</script> 
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: You should also include the relevant php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created the module two times for two controllers. Its not the right way of creating AngularJS module and controllers. Create the module once and add necessary contollers in to it.
The javascript code should like following:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("saAppModule", []);
app.controller("insertController", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.insert = function() {
        $http.post(
            "statementinsert.php", {
                'ID': $scope.ID,
                'Make': $scope.Make,
                'Model': $scope.Model,
                'Reg': $scope.Reg,
                'Owner': $scope.Owner,
                'Image': $scope.Image,

            }
        ).success(function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $scope.ID = null;
            $scope.Make = null;
            $scope.Model = null;
            $scope.Reg = null;
            $scope.Owner = null;
            $scope.Image = null;
        });
    }
});

app.controller("disPlayController", function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.display_data = function() {
            $http.get("statement.php")
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.names = data;
                });
        }
    });
</script>
```

And you have to use these controller appropriate way under separate template.